# How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Some documents I can't get the height of the document (to position something absolutely at the very bottom). Additionally, a padding-bottom on  seems to do nothing on these pages, but do on the pages where height will return. Case(s) in point:

http://fandango.com
http://paperbackswap.com

On Fandango
jQuery's `$(document).height();` returns correct value
`document.height` returns 0
`document.body.scrollHeight` returns 0

On Paperback Swap:
jQuery's `$(document).height();` TypeError: `$(document)` is null
`document.height` returns an incorrect value
`document.body.scrollHeight` returns an incorrect value

Note: I have browser level permissions, if there is some trick there.

Comment: $(document) is null because that site doesn't have jQuery loaded...

Comment: Hm, could have sworn I checked something else to confirm jQuery was registered but it doesn't look like I did, HA! I thought firebug had jQuery packaged... hm, I guess I will check this out then if it's a solution.

Comment: firebug does not have jQUery packaged

Comment: See [Finding the size of the browser window](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow). It has a great table of the behaviors of different browsers.

Answer (score 792, accepted):

Document sizes are a browser compatibility nightmare because, although all browsers expose clientHeight and scrollHeight properties, they don't all agree how the values are calculated.

There used to be a complex best-practice formula around for how you tested for correct height/width. This involved using document.documentElement properties if available or falling back on document properties and so on.

The simplest way to get correct height is to get all height values found on document, or documentElement, and use the highest one. This is basically what jQuery does:

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
```

A quick test with Firebug + [jQuery bookmarklet](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet) returns the correct height for both cited pages, and so does the code example.

Note that testing the height of the document before the document is ready will always result in a 0. Also, if you load more stuff in, or the user resizes the window, you may need to re-test. Use `onload` or a [document ready](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=document+ready) event if you need this at load time, otherwise just test whenever you need the number.

Comment: rate this solution, because it works when you are using prototype library, with jQuery there is no such issue

Comment: When working with iframes and jquery, because of this method of calculation, the iframe's document height will allways be at least the height of the iframe itselft. This is important to note when you want to reduce the iframe's height to match the content. You first have to reset the height of the iframe.

Comment: I had the need to grow the iframe and shrink it (facebook app) and found that document.body.offsetHeight was the best choice for me, accurately supported by the most browsers.

Comment: This is great although can give incorrect results if the document is not ready - ie, when used in server generated code...

Comment: Yeah.. and how many sites aren't generated these days.. 5%... I keep getting zero for my height.

Comment: Testing the document before it is ready won't work. This has nothing to do with generated code/documents but rather how the document is loaded. The test must run *after* the document is ready, and I would suggest running it only when the document is fully loaded as remaining items may affect the height, also resizing the browser.

Comment: What can be done to get the height, when some multimedia files like flash are embedded? Their height does not seem to be included in any of five possibilities you listed.

Comment: Amazing! Worked for me. When calculating, you will need to set it to execute this code on a resize event and onload because when the window is resized, the height of the document is likely to change.

Comment: It seems like this works without issues when used on an iframe, but try to use this on an iframe that is within another frame and you will get wrong results. (and yes, I confirmed it is targetting the inner iframe, though a number that should be 1240, comes back at 877). Any ideas?

Comment: @Borgar @www139 I am also doing it on `resize` event. But, for me the `contentWindow` is null. Could you please help

Comment: @KuldeepBhimte try adding a timeout on the resize listener for 0 milliseconds. I've found that, sometimes, the browser will fire both onload and resize at the same time when the page loads/renders. This can cause weird problems so that's why I'll generally add a small timeout before firing the first resize event.

Comment: @www139 , I just tried that, but still gets `null` for `contentDocument`

Comment: @KuldeepBhimte does it work with onload? This might be something to troubleshoot in a chat or make a new post.

Comment: @www139 I have some other issue with the iframe could you please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784044/anchor-tags-href-isnt-working-when-iframe-is-opened-in-a-react-dialog-model

Comment: This needs to be edited:
Note: body.scrollHeight could have absolute element which could increase "visible scroll/visible full" height of page.
If you would like to check "visible full height" of page you should check (element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight)

Answer (score 445):

This is a really old question, and thus, has many outdated answers. As of 2020 all [major browsers have adhered to the standard](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_element_scrollheight).

**Answer for 2020:**

```
document.body.scrollHeight
```

Edit: the above doesn't take margins on the `<body>` tag into account. If your body has margins, use:

```
document.documentElement.scrollHeight
```

Comment: As of 2017 this should be marked as the right answer to me.

Comment: @Joan That's up to the original poster to decide :)

Comment: Doesn't work in presence of margins. [`document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47362453/332528) works better.

Comment: There is one error with this: Say for example that there is an `<h1>` element at the start of the `<body>` with it's default margin, it will push the `<body>` element down without a way to detect it. `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` (not `document.body,scrollHeight`) is the most accurate way of doing things. This works with both body margins and margins of stuff inside the body pushing it downwards.

Comment: `window.innerHeight` appears to be identical to `document.documentElement.scrollHeight`, based on tests I just made in Chrome and Firefox. They both represent the full available height within the browser window. If you want to calculate the actual height available within the `body`, you must subtract the `body` element's top and bottom margins and/or padding (an 8px margin seems to be standard on `body`).  Note: `body` might not be the full available height, so `document.body.scrollHeight` is not reliable. But that's not the document height, it's available height of the visible area.

Answer (score 33):

**Full Document height calculation:**

To be more generic and find the height of **any document** you could just find the highest DOM Node on current page with a simple recursion:

```
;(function() {
    var pageHeight = 0;

    function findHighestNode(nodesList) {
        for (var i = nodesList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (nodesList[i].scrollHeight && nodesList[i].clientHeight) {
                var elHeight = Math.max(nodesList[i].scrollHeight, nodesList[i].clientHeight);
                pageHeight = Math.max(elHeight, pageHeight);
            }
            if (nodesList[i].childNodes.length) findHighestNode(nodesList[i].childNodes);
        }
    }

    findHighestNode(document.documentElement.childNodes);

    // The entire page height is found
    console.log('Page height is', pageHeight);
})();
```

You can Test it on your sample sites (http://fandango.com/ or http://paperbackswap.com/) with pasting this script to a DevTools Console.

NOTE: it is working with `Iframes`.

Enjoy!

Comment: This worked like a charm!
No other answer here works to get the full height (including scrollable area), they all return only height of visible area.

Comment: Really exceptional, never thought of this. Only one working in phantomjs I suppose.

Answer (score 30):

You can even use this:

```
var B = document.body,
    H = document.documentElement,
    height

if (typeof document.height !== 'undefined') {
    height = document.height // For webkit browsers
} else {
    height = Math.max( B.scrollHeight, B.offsetHeight,H.clientHeight, H.scrollHeight, H.offsetHeight );
}
```

or in a more jQuery way (since as you said jQuery doesn't lie) :)

```
Math.max($(document).height(), $(window).height())
```

Answer (score 7):

**The proper answer for 2017 is:**

`document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height`

Unlike `document.body.scrollHeight` this method accounts for body margins.
It also gives fractional height value, which can be useful in some cases

Comment: These are the results I get when I try your method on this page: https://i.imgur.com/0psVkIk.png Your method returns something that looks like the window height, while `document.body.scrollHeight` lists the entire scrollable height, which is what the original question asked.

Comment: @Marquizzo that's because this page has `html { height: 100% }` in css. So the API correctly returns the **real** calculated height. Try removing this style and also adding margins to `body` and you will see what's the problem with using `document.body.scrollHeight`.

Comment: There is one error with this: Say for example that there is an `<h1>` element at the start of the `<body>` with it's default margin, it will push the `<body>` element down without a way to detect it. `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` (not `document.body,scrollHeight`) is the most accurate way of doing things.

Comment: @Booligoosh not sure what you mean. `documentElement.scrollHeight` gives a wrong value in this case. `documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height` gives the correct one. check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/fLpqjsxd/

Comment: @torvin The .documentElement one works: https://jsfiddle.net/fLpqjsxd/5/

Comment: @Booligoosh as you can see in your fiddle, `documentElement.scrollHeight` only works properly when there is a need for a scroll bar, while `documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height` works correctly in both cases.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on this very page.
`document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height` : `1299`.


`document.documentElement.scrollHeight` : `9031`


`document.body.scrollHeight` : `9031`


Also see screenshot here : [![document-document-Element-get-Bounding-Client-Rect-height-shows-wron.png](https://i.postimg.cc/v8nGkfCX/document-document-Element-get-Bounding-Client-Rect-height-shows-wron.png)](https://postimg.cc/qgkfChJC)

Comment: @RobWaa see comments above about this very page

Comment: @torvin Fact remains that not the intended result is returned by `getBoundingClientRect().height`. It gets sidetracked, while 3 (three) other methods don't get sidetracked. Including the one that you mention as inferior to it. And you insist on doing so by suggesting to remove 100% from this page's html height, and adding margins to it. What's the point ? Just accept that `getBoundingClientRect().height` is also not bullet-proof.

Comment: @RobWaa I suggest to add margins to show that using `scrollHeight` returns incorrect results in this case. The behaviour of `getBoundingClientRect()` makes total sense to me. If it doesn't for you - feel free to use whatever else.

Comment: @torvin So this page was only 1299px high, instead of 9031px. :/ Like I commented earlier, none of these methods (4x) is bullet proof. You can't preach that one is more appropriate than the other because it's "for 2017". The fact that your suggested method falters in 2019 is proof of that. No matter how much you try to tarnish the other methods.


Better measure with 2 or more of those 4 methods. So first investigate the DOM, then execute the most reliable method. It's somewhat similar to browser capability testing. If you prefer to depend one one method, than go for it. It's your party.

Comment: The truth is, "the height of the document" doesn't exist in HTML. You can measure only the height of an element. If your `<html>` has `height=100%` it won't match what you think "the document" is. But it **is** what the browser thinks.

Answer (score 6):

The "jQuery method" of determining the document size - query everything, take the highest value, and hope for the best - works in most cases, but [not in all of them](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.documentsize#what-does-it-do-that-jquery-doesnt) .

If you *really* need bullet-proof results for the document size, I'd suggest you use my [jQuery.documentSize](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.documentsize) plugin. Unlike the other methods, it actually tests and evaluates browser behaviour when it is loaded and, based on the result, queries the right property from there on out.

The impact of this one-time test on performance [is minimal](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.documentsize#performance), and the plugin returns the right results in even the weirdest scenarios - not because I say so, but because a massive, auto-generated test suite actually verifies that it does.

Because the plugin is written in vanilla Javascript, you can use it [without jQuery](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.documentsize#dependencies-and-setup), too.

Answer (score 5):

I lied, jQuery returns the correct value for both pages $(document).height();... why did I ever doubt it?

Comment: Different browsers bro.

Answer (score 2):

To get the width in a cross browser/device way use:

```
function getActualWidth() {
    var actualWidth = window.innerWidth ||
                      document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
                      document.body.clientWidth ||
                      document.body.offsetWidth;

    return actualWidth;
}
```

Comment: we are talking about height. not width.

Answer (score 1):

This cross browser code below evaluates all possible heights of the body and html elements and returns the max found:

```
            var body = document.body;
            var html = document.documentElement;
            var bodyH = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, body.getBoundingClientRect().height, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight); // The max height of the body
```

### A working example:

```js
function getHeight()
{
  var body = document.body;
  var html = document.documentElement; 
  var bodyH = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, body.getBoundingClientRect().height, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
  return bodyH;
}

document.getElementById('height').innerText = getHeight();
```

```css
body,html
{
  height: 3000px;
}

#posbtm
{
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: Yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="posbtm">The max Height of this document is: <span id="height"></span> px</div>

example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
example document body content example document body content example document body content example document body content <br />
```

Comment: Please explicate the motivation in case of downvoting so I can correct the point. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having trouble scrolling a page on demand, using feature detection, I've come up with this hack to detect which feature to use in an animated scroll.

The issue was both `document.body.scrollTop` and `document.documentElement` always returned `true` in all browsers.

However you can only actually scroll a document with either one or the other. `d.body.scrollTop` for Safari and `document.documentElement` for all others according to [w3schools (see examples)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp)

`element.scrollTop` works in all browsers, not so for document level.

```
    // get and test orig scroll pos in Saf and similar 
    var ORG = d.body.scrollTop; 

    // increment by 1 pixel
    d.body.scrollTop += 1;

    // get new scroll pos in Saf and similar 
    var NEW = d.body.scrollTop;

    if(ORG == NEW){
        // no change, try scroll up instead
        ORG = d.body.scrollTop;
        d.body.scrollTop -= 1;
        NEW = d.body.scrollTop;

        if(ORG == NEW){
            // still no change, use document.documentElement
            cont = dd;
        } else {
            // we measured movement, use document.body
            cont = d.body;
        }
    } else {
        // we measured movement, use document.body
        cont = d.body;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

use blow code for compute height + scroll

```
var dif = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;

var height = dif + document.documentElement.scrollHeight +"px";
```

Answer (score -4):

**Add References properly**

In my case I was using a ASCX page and the aspx page that contains the ascx control is not using the references properly.
I just pasted the following code and it worked :

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -5):

I don't know about determining height just now, but you can use this to put something on the bottom:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CSS bottom test</title>
<style>
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 1em;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p>regular body stuff.</p>

<div class='bottom'>on the bottom</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Trust me, I have exhausted HTML and CSS resources on this one. Can't explain it but you will see the issues if you try this on those sites.