# Webview height not changing after resize font size

Tags: android, webview, height

In my application I use a ScrollView. This ScrollView contain many Webview.
I change the webview font size:

```
webView.getSettings().setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.LARGER);
```

after I change again the font size:

```
webView.getSettings().setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.SMALLER);
```

The font size is changing, but the webview layout height is not changing. The text is smaller and there are a big space.
There are any method to this problem?

Comment: Look at my solution on another similar post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973565/how-to-resize-a-android-webview-after-adding-data-in-it/25187094#25187094

Answer (score 0):

you might have to reload your webview with ie:

```
webview.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );
```

Comment: Sorry, but not working....During I solved the problem, I need to remove the webview and after add a new webview.

Comment: glad you found your solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it using code:

```
private void reloadWebView() {
    postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            clearView();
            requestLayout();
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

Call it method when You have finished zooming. It will refresh web view and recalculate it size.

Comment: FYI, I add to re-load the WebView content after I called `clearView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
private void reloadWebView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            clearView();
            reload();               
            myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            requestLayout();
        }
    }, 10);
}
```