# How to change webview size (window.innerWidth; window.innerHeight)?

Tags: android, android-webview

How can I change Webview (window.innerWidth; window.innerHeight)? WebSettings seem doesn't has method to do that.

**EDIT:**
I add solution here for simplification:

```
webView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                200, // width
                200 // height
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Source: [How to resize a android webview after adding data in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973565/how-to-resize-a-android-webview-after-adding-data-in-it/25187094#25187094)

```
private void setupWebView() {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:MyApp.resize(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)");
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MyApp");
}
@JavascriptInterface
public void resize(final float height) {
    MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, (int) (height * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please do not copy-paste solutions. This was taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25187094/9763253)

Comment: Added Source Link, Thank You Ümañg ßürmån