# Instagram post according to size in webview Android

Tags: java, android, webview, instagram-api

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webViewInstagram"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="500dp">
```

My Instagram webview I don't want to make the size of the webview static(500dp) I tried wrap_content but it is not working and I want it to dynamic according to the Instagram post size. But I am getting only a shared Instagram link.
Already tried invalidate(),reload().
Is there any other way to change the size of webview according to the size of the post.

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25187094/10778405

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10778405/s-t tried to but not able to as my webview is in an adapter.