# determine if a UIWebView requires scrolling

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview

This is an update to a earlier question.  Once I load up a UIWebView with some string based HTML content, is there a way to determine if the view would require scrolling to see the entirety of the content?  I am looking for some sort of flag or way of knowing if content is below the bottom of the UIWebView.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass UIWebView and use the following initalizers:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        for (UIView* v in self.subviews){
            if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
                self.scrollview = (UIScrollView*)v; 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        for (UIView* v in self.subviews){
            if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
                self.scrollview = (UIScrollView*)v; 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

then have a property called

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollview;
```

You then have access to the scrollview within the UIWebView and can check its content size to see if it is bigger than your views size

Comment: This is kinda working, great idea.  

I did the check like this: (w being my subclassed webview)


[w loadHTMLString:content  baseURL:url];
   [scrollIssue addSubview:w];
   
   
   CGRect rect = w.frame;
   UIScrollView *sv = [w scrollview];
   CGSize rectv = sv.contentSize;

They are always the same even when it needs to scroll.  Suspecting it is not painted, is there a way to force it to layout prior to the check?

Comment: could try a call to layoutSubviews on the webview?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to use Javascript to get the document height:

NSInteger height = [[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight"] intValue];

(haven't actually tested this so YMMV. Different browsers put the document height in different objects and properties and I can't remember which one works in Webkit... see [How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript))

If the height returned is greater than the UIWebView height it's going to need scrolling.