# Getting a WebView's total scroll size ( the size of the HTML content )

Tags: cocoa, macos, webkit, webview

I'm trying lots of things, posted many questions here, but I still can't manage to get the minimum size needed to hold an HTML page in a Cocoa WebKit WebView.
I made a weird manipulation of the DOM where I can get an approximation of the size of the HTML contents, as you can see in the picture, I resize the window based on this, and almost works, but what I realize is this:
If the Webview is intelligent enough to show accurate scroll bars (of course it is) so how come there's no interface so the programmer can get that value? is there a way that you know of?

PS: please don't provide javascript solutions, I need to implement this from the application. Anyway an html API as Webkit should be more savvy about its content than the hosted javascript code, shouldn't it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript to get the proper height.

Adapted from: [How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript/1147768#1147768)

```
(function () {
    var body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;

    return Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                        html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
})();
```

This Javascript will give you the height of the HTML. You can inject it into the WebView like this:

```
NSString *height = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"(function(){var a=document.body,b=document.documentElement;return Math.max(a.scrollHeight,a.offsetHeight,b.clientHeight,b.scrollHeight,b.offsetHeight)})();"];
```

`height` now contains the height of the HTML as a string.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this and doesn't work. body and html don't return any size.  
I can access this from the application via the DOM, but again body.scrollHeight and the other just don't have any values.  
Anyway, my application runs user-supplied htmls son I can't require any javascript code, I need to manage it from the application side.

Comment: Correction, both body and html return the client size, which is the size of the window I set from the application, not the size of the html content.

Comment: Are you running it in your `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(WebView *)theWebView;` delegate method?

Answer (score 0):

While the solution by Alec Gorge worked for me, when placing the code into the `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate method, I found that at least in iOS (and probably in OSX's Webkit as well) I could get the height of the web view just as well using this code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    int h = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    self.myWebViewHeightConstraint.constant = h;
}
```

Comment: That starts like Objective-C, but UIWebViews are iOS. Am I correct?