# Show footer if at bottom of page or page is short else hide

Tags: jquery, html, css

Check out my jsFiddle to see what is going on: http://jsfiddle.net/Amp3rsand/EDWHX/2/

If you uncomment the second .content div in the article you will see the footer hiding like it should then un-hiding when you get to the bottom of the page. My trouble is that I would like it to show the footer when the content is shorter than the viewport like when the second .content div is commented out.

(ie. window.height > document.height right?)

On my actual website the .content divs are replaced by different divs with unique id's for each page so I couldn't figure out how to target them specifically. Is what I'm doing the correct way to do it?

Here is my code for the people who don't want to use the jsFiddle for some reason:

HTML

```
<article>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <!--
        <div class="content"></div>
    -->
</article>

<footer>
            <ul id="footerlinks">
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
</footer>
<div id="underfooter"></div>
```

CSS

```
article {
    min-height: 500px;
    background: black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.content {
    height:500px;
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -50px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-top:2px solid #6ce6d5;
    background: white;
    z-index: 100;
}

#underfooter {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -44px;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 90;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('footer').data('size','hide');
});




$(window).scroll(function(){

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 0)
    {
        if($('footer').data('size') == 'hide')
        {
            $('footer').data('size','show');
            $('footer').stop().animate({
                bottom:'0px'
            },400);
            $('#white2').stop().animate({
                bottom:'6px'
            },400);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($('footer').data('size') == 'show')
        {
            $('footer').data('size','hide');
            $('footer').stop().animate({
                bottom:'-50px'
            },400);
            $('#white2').stop().animate({
                bottom:'-44px'
            },400);
        }  
    }
});




$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).height() >= $(document).height() )
    {
        $('footer').data('size','hide');
    }
    else
    {
        $('footer').data('size','big');
    }
});
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

See if this is what you want. Made a lot of changes to your JS which was quite a lot for me:
***http://jsfiddle.net/EDWHX/3/***

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('footer').hide();
    if($(document).height() < $(window).height()){
        $('footer').show();
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){
        console.log("resized");
       if($(document).height() > $(window).height()){
           console.log("hide footer now");
            $('footer').slideUp('slow');
        }
        else{
            $('footer').slideDown('slow');
        }
    });
});



$(window).scroll(function(){        
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 0)
    {
            $('footer').slideDown('slow');
            $('#white2').stop().animate({
                bottom:'6px'
            },400);
    }
    else
    {
            $('footer').slideUp('slow');
            $('#white2').stop().animate({
                bottom:'-44px'
            },400);
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).height() >= $(document).height() )
    {
        $('footer').data('size','hide');
    }
    else
    {
        $('footer').data('size','show');
    }
});
```

CSS Changes:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
        bottom:0px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-top:2px solid #6ce6d5;
    background: white;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do all that. Could you talk me through your changes though? Your fiddle isn't working the way I was hoping for when the content is shorter than the viewport. It works great for when it is longer though. Is there any benefit to doing it the way you do it vs mine?

Comment: all right..let me try to explain. although it should work for both the cases. let me see what went wrong here.

Comment: I managed to get mine working the way I hoped just then, I realised that the document.ready function wasn't doing anything besides changing the data. Check it out here if you would like:http://jsfiddle.net/Amp3rsand/EDWHX/4/ Is your method better than mine?

Comment: ...I checked out your fiddle. But, I see that when the content is shorter than the window, the footer doesn't show up, which is not what you wanted. Correct ?

Comment: Hmm interesting. For me the footer is showing up like I want both on the jsfiddle and on the test version of my website using my method.

Comment: great, then. Wanted it to work for you at the end of the day!

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated the jsfiddle, you should use document.body.offsetHeight to get the height of the "content".

Look at this answer: [How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript)

And check the jsfiddle for the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/juaning/EDWHX/5/

`$(document).ready(function() {
    var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;
    console.log(body.offsetHeight >= html.offsetHeight , body.offsetHeight , html.offsetHeight);
    $('footer').data('size','show');
    if (body.offsetHeight >= html.offsetHeight )
    {
        $('footer').data('size','hide');
        console.log('hide');
    }
    else
    {
        $('footer').data('size','show');
        $('footer').stop().animate({
                bottom:'0px'
            },400);
            $('#white2').stop().animate({
                bottom:'6px'
            },400);
        console.log('show');
    }
});`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to get this working myself right after you posted this but yours seems to do a lot more. What are the benefits from doing it your way vs mine? See http://jsfiddle.net/Amp3rsand/EDWHX/4/ for my revised version if you feel like it