# CSS - how to style a footer

Tags: css

is there a way to style a footer, so when there is a content (more than the height of the browser) it will be at bottom of the page(hidden), but if there is not enough content it will stick at bottom edge of the browser?

Comment: Just put it at the bottom of the page and use `min-height`. As long as there's nothing after the footer, it will take up the rest of the page.

Comment: read this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page then look into jquery waypoints

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution I use requires a known height of your footer.

Fiddles:

[**A lot of content**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hVyy/1)

[**A little content**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hVyy/2/)

Here's the HTML:

```
<main>
  hello
</main>
<footer>
  i am the footer
</footer>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
main {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    background: #ddd;
}
main:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
}
footer {
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
}
```

The trick is to set the main part of your document to have a `min-height` of 100%. This element must contain everything else on your page. In my example, I used the `main` element for this.

Next, give this element a negative margin equal to the height of the footer. This moves it up just enough to leave room for the footer there at the bottom.

The last piece of the puzzle is the `after` element. This is required to fill the space of that negative margin. Otherwise, the content of the `main` will overflow into the footer.

Comment: this does not work http://jsfiddle.net/9hVyy/.... content is going in the footer just try many <br/> and type "end" and this "end" is the footer.

Comment: It works great if you keep the main:after styles intact. Good job James.

Answer (score 1):

I can only recommend to read this. 
[Show footer if at bottom of page or page is short else hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326708/show-footer-if-at-bottom-of-page-or-page-is-short-else-hide)

or this
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the calc function in CSS to make out the difference in between the footer and the body height.

footer {

```
 height: calc(100vh - 100px);
```

}

for example...