# How to get full height of the page using js?

Tags: javascript

I am trying get full height of the page in browser but I only able to get only visible portion height of the page,but I need whole visible and hidden page height.My js code are given below:

Js:

```
var _docHeight = (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight;
```

Any idea how to get the full visible and also hidden page height that appear in the full browser?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript

Comment: your code works fine in all latest browsers. Can you give me your browser name and its version

Comment: See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1147768/2525067) on the same question. It' works in any browser build in twenty century

Comment: firefox 24,its working fine but only show visible portion height in the browser and i wont both visible and hidden height of the page in the browser.@Pinal

Comment: firefox 24,its working fine but only show visible portion height in the browser and i wont both visible and hidden height of the page in the browser @kundan