# Trying to trigger event on certain scroll height using javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

```
var amount = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-total-qty")[0].innerHTML;
console.log(amount);

var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
var tenPercent = height*.9

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    scrollAmount = window.scrollY;
    if(scrollAmount == tenPercent){
    alert("It's happening (Insert Ron Paul)");
    }
});
```

In my code above i am getting the height of the page using an example i found here: [How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript)

I am then trying to trigger an event once the user has scrolled to the bottom ten percent of the page. The problem is that `scrollAmount` does not ever reach within 10% of `height`

In my example `height` is returned as 1280 and `scrollAmount` never returns higher then 1040 while scrolling, but the strange part is that if i change the height of my browser i get different results for `scrollAmount` when i scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is expected that `scrollAmount` would return a value significantly lower than content height of the document. If you look closer, maximum value of it is actually (content height - window height). Think of it like this: suppose your content was just one pixel longer than available window height, in that case what should be the maximum `scrollAmount`? I'd expect it to be 1.
So replace your `tenPercent = height*.9` with `tenPercent = (height-window.innerHeight)*.9`

Second, you scroll in steps of 100px or so. Sure some animation may be there, but event doesn't fire constantly for every possible value of `scrollAmount`. It is unlikely that during scroll, `scrollAmount` would exactly be equal to `tenPercent`. So replace your `scrollAmount == tenPercent` with `scrollAmount > tenPercent`

Comment: Thank you this was what i needed. Also thanks for pointing out my mistake with the ==