# jQuery returns wrong document height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cocoa

I'm using a Webview in Cocoa (Mac), and I'm trying to get the correct height of a document. Just doing the normal thing, `webview.mainFrame.frameView.documentView.bounds.size.height` seems to work fine in all cases, except one that I just found:

**http://www.medium.com**.

When I try doing that on this site, I get a document height of something like 500, when the real document height is more like 2000+, since I have to scroll several screens to get to the end.

I tried resorting to evaluating javascript in the webview to get the actual height, using approaches like the ones listed here: [How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript)

But these also gave grossly incorrect values, like my initial approach. Even going to that page, loading jQuery, then doing stuff like $(document.body).height() gives a grossly incorrect value. Anyone know what is going on? Is there some other way of getting the document height that is reliable?

I noticed that the heights reported by the inspector in chrome are getting confused also. In these screenshots, you can see the document.body height being reported as less than the height of one of its child nodes.

[image: medium.com body height in chrome inspector]
[image: medium.com body->child div height in chrome inspector]

Comment: This is really an interesting issue.

Comment: I've changed the title - I think this is more appropriate and should attract more attention. It's really a bug, easily reproduced by opening http://medium.com/ and activating a [jQuerify bookmarklet](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet/)

Comment: I think this is real bug, you should report it to http://bugs.jquery.com/.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14705

Comment: As detailed in my response below, this is not a jQuery bug, but a design-choice by the team of Medium. I don't think this warrants as a defect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing with this page is the following:

The HTML and Body (and a few of the underlying elements) are all set to a 100% height, so they fit exactly in the browser-window. In my case that is about 500pixels high. How do they establish this scrolling then? Well... There is a div with a overflow:auto and the actual content is way more (around 4000px)

So you are in fact not scrolling the whole page, but this specific div (check out layout-foreground scrolling-region)

In this case it is totally correct that the height of the document is 500px, the height you are looking for can be found this way via the console:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".scrolling-region")[0].scrollHeight
```

That will give you the height of 4133px, which is, in this case, the actual height of the page.

Cheers :)

Comment: I should have known. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `html,body{height:100%}` and `.screen-scroll,.screen-scroll>body{overflow:hidden}` are messing things up for you. If you set them both to `height:100%` and set body to `overflow:hidden` then html and body will both have the same `100%` height with no `overflow`, which will make the `document` height the same as the `window` height.

So it may be that you're actually looking for the sum of the heights of `header, nav, and .background-white` instead, which would be more like `4222` and not like the `500` you are getting now.

**something like this:**

```
var hh = $('header').height(),
    nh = $('nav').height(),
    bh = $('.background-white').height(),
    docHeight = hh+nh+bh;
alert(docHeight);//test
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are getting the window.innerWidth/Height and not the entire document.

Try this out.

```
document.body.offsetHeight
```

I tried it on a random webpage and got +8000 px, that seamed to be right. My window height was only 590 (with the console open ofc).

Hope it helps.

- Molle

Comment: Tried that, but it does not work for the case I'm talking about: www.medium.com.

Comment: weird that this gives a different value from `window.innerHeight`

Answer (score 0):

```
var D = document;
        var docHeight = Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );

var height1= $(window).height(),
    height= $(document).height();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that, but it gives the wrong answer in this case. Try it for medium.com.

Answer (score 0):

How about wait before page loads?
$(document).ready(function(){..});

I have same issue in Chrome. On one site it was necessary to adjust the height of the two columns with js. When I click F5 one of the columns has different height, fix that with $(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen on all browsers, or just chrome?

On 1/15, chrome updated their browser, which changed a few notable things, but one of them has to do with calculating the browser window/viewport. Here's the post, perhaps it will help: http://blogs.telerik.com/jefffritz/posts/14-01-17/chrome-updated-scrollTop

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing the same issue. After one whole day's effort I realized that, but if I call the statement inside window.onload, it returns right height.