# How to get the entire width and height of a document (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

On a button click I want to make a `div` that is the entire width and height of the page. Not just the visible page but the entire rendered document.

So far I am using Javascript from [this SO anser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript) to calculate the height:

```
 var B = document.body,
     H = document.documentElement,
     height;
            if (typeof document.height !== 'undefined') {
                height = document.height;
            } else {
                height = Math.max( B.scrollHeight, B.offsetHeight, H.clientHeight, H.scrollHeight, H.offsetHeight );
            }
            var overlay = document.createElement('div');
            overlay.style.position = 'absolute';
            overlay.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
            overlay.style.height = height + 'px';
            overlay.style.top = window.scrollY + 'px';
            overlay.style.left = 0;
```

However this does not always work.  Sometimes when I am scrolled down to the bottom of the page the overlay starts lower on the page and extends the length of the document significantly.  Sometimes it works right and sometimes it does not.  I know there are ways to do this with jQuery but I do not want to use this.

Bonus points would be the best way to keep the overlay stretching across the entire screen width upon windows resize....Thanks

Comment: to have an element to overlay only the screen and stay there, then use : `el{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;}` you may allow it to scroll with `overflow:auto;` if needed.

Comment: If you just want a overlay I was gona suggest what GCyrillus said; http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/6x9er14L/

Comment: @Travisj, I looked at all these answers, most of which are old, and they did not work consistently. Wondering if there is a new and better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an approach where you place an element at the bottom right corner of the page and then look at the offset if the window changes sizes

```
var getDimensions = document.createElement("div");
getDimensions.setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden;position:fixed;bottom:0px;right:0px;");
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(getDimensions);
var Width = getDimensions.offsetLeft;
var Height = getDimensions.offsetTop;
window.onresize = function(){
 Width = getDimensions.offsetLeft;
 Height = getDimensions.offsetTop;
};
```

Comment: This looks pretty good to me.  Why is it so hard to just calculate the damn width and height of the document?

Comment: @Startec - It gets complicated when the sizes change (or if you need to consider scrollbars which this accounts for).

Answer (score 0):

Get the width in a cross browser/device way use:

```
function _getActualWidth()
{
    _actualWidth = window.innerWidth ||
                   document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
                   document.body.clientWidth ||
                   document.body.offsetWidth;

    return _actualWidth;
}
```

To get the height replace Width by Height. You can call these functions when a resize events is emitted and then set the new width and height to your overlay object.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use [CSS viewport units](http://dev.opera.com/articles/css-viewport-units/) instead of trying to calculate the viewport width and height?

```
        overlay.style.width = '100vw';
        overlay.style.height = '100vh';
```

Comment: I'm going to study up on these, I didn't know they existed.  These units are definitely a feature of CSS[1,2,3], not specific to Opera, correct?

Comment: Here is why I wouldn't use those: They have bad browser support. Yes @abiessu, they are new to CSS3 but have the worst support of all new length properties. Even worse than `rem`s  but they are going to be great for responsive text et al.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on what browsers you need to support. `vh` and `vw` works in IE9+.