# Anyway of detecting appropriate width based on page content for a JS popup?

Tags: javascript, window.open

Is there a way of detecting the width of the content that will contain a JavaScript popup?

I'm trying to avoid hard-coding a width, as the content within the page that is the location for the JavaScript popup could change at any given time.

Comment: Is the popup on the same domain? Or do you have access to the popup content?

Comment: Use line breaks instead

Comment: @RGraham the popup is on the same domain. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript) on how to calculate the document height. You should be able to use `windowReference.resizeTo` to resize the window to the calculated height/width