# React native: Is it possible to have the height of a html content in a webview?

Tags: webview, scrollview, react-native

I'm getting html content from an api and I want to render it as a web view in my application.

The webview component is nested in a scrollview because it has some other contents above my render function is something like this:

```js
render() {
      var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>' + this.state.pushEvent.Description + '</body></html>';

    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.recipe}>
          <Image source={{uri: this.state.pushEvent.ImageUrl}}
            style={styles.imgFull} />
          <Text style={styles.title}>{this.state.pushEvent.Title}</Text>
          
          <WebView style={{padding: 20}}
            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            html={html}>
          </WebView>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

The problem is that my html is just 20pt high that is my padding. Is there a clever way to get the height of the content?

Comment: I've used @hedgerwang hack to let my WebView comunicate via document.title its height, here is the [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/586#issuecomment-90826117) but there should be a better way without installing external npm

Comment: I answered solution on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446209/react-native-webview-height/55889904#55889904
Hope this help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I wrote on the comment above this is what I came out with, but I'm still thinking that there should be a better solution.

Here is the issue on github I took inspiration from: [@hedgerwang answer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/586#issuecomment-90826117)

In my var html I added a simple script just before the closing body tag, I simply save the height of my html in my document title:

```
<script>window.location.hash = 1;document.title = document.height;</script>
```

then I added onNavigationStateChange props in my WebView component with a callback that set a state "height" variable and then set this height to my WebView. As I said, that did the trick, with just a little flahsing while changing the content in the WebView, but I think it's a dirty hack.

At the end I decided to change the api to have something that I don't have to include in a WebView

But maybe this can help, here the full code.

```
onNavigationStateChange(navState) {
  this.setState({
    height: navState.title,
  });
}  
render() {
  var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>' + this.state.pushEvent.Description + '<script>window.location.hash = 1;document.title = document.height;</script></body></html>';
return (
  <ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.recipe}>
      <Image source={{uri: this.state.pushEvent.ImageUrl}}
        style={styles.imgFull} />
      <Text style={styles.title}>{this.state.pushEvent.Title}</Text>

      <WebView style={{padding: 20}}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
        html={html}>
      </WebView>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up implementing it like this https://gist.github.com/epeli/10c77c1710dd137a1335 This version will also handle images but still fails for any other dynamic content.

Comment: This seems to no longer work (RN 0.28) -- like the comments to Daniel's answer below indicate (injecting JavaScript), the navState.title attribute now seems to be ridiculously large...for one line of text, the value is 568 for me...

Comment: This doesn't work in React Native Version 0.30
Height is always 0.
And I think it should change the import something like this.
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {WebView, View, Text} from "react-native";

Comment: Sorry, This code is working fine, it was my mistake, I should add the script code just before </body> but I added it just after <body>.

Thanks

Comment: The calculated height seems to be wrong in Android -  The bigger the page the more it is wrong.   Any ideas how to rectify?

Comment: This doesn't work on Android when keyboard is showing. Any idea of fix?

Comment: confirmed, this is not working on Android, only in iOS, any idea?

Comment: If you're trying to implement this now, note that document.height is obsolete. Instead use document.body.clientHeight.

Comment: I am getting 0  always when using  `document.body.clientHeight`

Comment: also, try checking `document.body.scrollHeight` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44077777/9108471) because it worked for me

Answer (score 10):

There is a better way to do it: you can inject custom JS with the **injectedJavaScript** property. The result of the evaluation will end up in the event object you receive in your **onNavigationStateChange**.
This way you won't have to modify the HTML itself or hijack the title property.

See https://gist.github.com/dbasedow/ed6e099823cb8d5ab30e for an example

Comment: This one's so much better and neat

Answer (score 0):

This component worked perfectly for me. It adjusts the webview to fit the content and returns the height of the rendered html.

https://gist.github.com/epeli/10c77c1710dd137a1335

And change

```
import React, {WebView, View, Text} from "react-native";
```

for

```
import React from "react";
import {WebView, View, Text} from "react-native";
```

at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way for doing this is through postMessage, in the injectedJavascript prop (just as in [this component](https://github.com/scazzy/react-native-webview-autoheight).

Pass document.scrollHeight in there and you're all set.

```
const jsString = `
  function post () {
    postMessage(
      Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.clientHeight, document.body.scrollHeight)
    );
  }
  setTimeout(post, 200);
// other custom js you may want
`


// component class:
  _onMessage = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      webviewHeight: parseInt(e.nativeEvent.data)
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={yourURL}

        injectedJavascript={jsString}
        onMessage={this._onMessage}

        style={{ height: webviewHeight }}
      />
    )
  }
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The _onMessage-function is not even called, when I try out the code...

Comment: you could try increasing the # of milliseconds in ```setTimeout(post, 200)```; maybe the document is not ready yet

Comment: RN 0.64.1 this doesn't work even after 10 seconds sadly.

Comment: It's dangerous to create race conditions, do not do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HandleHTMLDimensionsFeature` provided by [@formidable-webview/webshell](https://formidable-webview.github.io/webshell/) library. It will use `injectedJavaScript` to run a script in the `WebView`.
This is how you would use it:

```js
import React from 'react';
import makeWebshell, {
  HandleHTMLDimensionsFeature
} from '@formidable-webview/webshell';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

const Webshell = makeWebshell(
  WebView,
  new HandleHTMLDimensionsFeature()
);

export default function AugmentedWebview(props) {
  const onDocumentDimensions = React.useCallback(
    (dimensions) => {
      console.info(dimensions.content);
    },
    []
  );
  return (
    <Webshell
      onDOMHTMLDimensions={onDocumentDimensions}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

The script run in the Web environement [is available here](https://github.com/formidable-webview/webshell/blob/b374e9bc004c65479fadb1d95f4bac64eef858fa/packages/webshell/src/features/HandleHTMLDimensionsFeature.webjs).
The dimensions will be sent each time the document size changes, dynamically. The script will use the best API available in the `WebView`, by order of preference,
[ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver),
[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)
and finally, polling on a regular interval. If you are looking for an autoheight `WebView`, [check out this guide](https://formidable-webview.github.io/webshell/docs/autoheight).