# React Native dynamic webview height

Tags: javascript, webview, reactjs, react-native

I have WebView content are which changes it's height depending on amount of content. 
So I found a way how to take the height of the content through the document.title attribute onNavigationStateChange.
Looks like this:

```
let html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script>document.title = document.height;</script></body></html>';
```

And on onNavigationStateChange

```
onNavigationStateChange(navState) {
  this.setState({
    height: navState.title
  });
  console.log("DATA");
  console.log(this.state.height)
}
```

On the actual WebView render I do:

```
<WebView style={this._setWebviewHeight()}
           automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
           scrollEnabled={false}
           onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
           html={html}>
</WebView>
```

Where:

```
_setWebviewHeight() {
 return {
  height: this.state.height,
  padding: 20,
 }
}
```

And in this case I'm getting error and I am not able to get the height of content through state. What shall I do then?

The idea of solution is taken from here: [React native: Is it possible to have the height of a html content in a webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952270/react-native-is-it-possible-to-have-the-height-of-a-html-content-in-a-webview)

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution in the implementation of one of the RN third party libraries.
Here is the link to it: 
https://github.com/danrigsby/react-native-web-container/blob/master/index.js

With this kind of approach all worked good.

Comment: It returns undefined

Answer (score 2):

Just try this lib: https://github.com/iou90/react-native-autoheight-webview
It will works both on iOS & Android