# React-native: Flexbox styling of Webview not working when setting HTML source

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I'm new to styling with flexbox etc...
We have an existing backend with a Q/A system. When calling the API Answers will be returned in HTML. I render the answer in a static webview in my react-native app ~ like so:

```
<View style={{margin: 16}}> 
 [..]
  <Webview source={{html: solution.description}} style={{flex:1}} />
```

unfortunately the solution only gets displayed when setting a height - this is impossible since I dont know the solutions length. It doesn't seem to depend on the html - I set it to an example like:

```
      var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>This is a heading!</body></html>';
```

which results in the same problem.

**Edit:**
Screenshot
[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi can you at least post screenshots of your app? So that people can understand your problem better.

Comment: Sure - I added one. Not sure how it helps though, since the problem is that it doesn't show anything.
Under the thumbnail of user "Api User" should be a description of the solution..

Comment: Can't see the screenshot! :|

Comment: eh? I can see it, also after deleting the cache... maybe check on your end?

Comment: damn corporate firewall. I had to proxy it. I can see now. Please wait..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that there is no way to resize your webview height to match the contents. However, I found these links to be helpful for your particular issue.

1. [React Native dynamic webview height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454311/react-native-dynamic-webview-height)
2. [Github](https://github.com/danrigsby/react-native-web-container/blob/master/index.js)
3. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/epeli/10c77c1710dd137a1335)

The second link would surely patch your issue. However, you'll need to refactor a bit. Good luck!

Comment: thx - the repo linked seems to solve the issue. I'll need to refactor it into my code though, since the package on npm is broken. have a good one!

Comment: haha this was actually a coincidence that it set a height correctly. apparently this worked only stable with previous RN versions. e.g. it returns a height of 667 for 1line of text.. damn back to the drawing board