# React native: webview height

Tags: webview, react-native

Hi I know it's a known issue about the auto height of webview in react native,
and I have tried all the possibles solutions I've found on the internet such as :

https://gist.github.com/epeli/10c77c1710dd137a1335

https://github.com/danrigsby/react-native-web-container/blob/master/index.js

and all the solutions suggested in:
[React native: Is it possible to have the height of a html content in a webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952270/react-native-is-it-possible-to-have-the-height-of-a-html-content-in-a-webview)

But unfortunately none of these seems to work for me, 
I understand that the workaround they all suggest is to set the title to the height, but in my case it seems that the title always stays the same which is : 
"text/html ...." and the rest of my html.
I get the html content from an API, it comes without a body, head or html tags, I've also tried adding these tags manually to the html and nothing seems to work.

I would love to hear if anyone else had that problem and how did it get fixed.

Comment: I have same problem, I added  javaScriptEnabled={true} and javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true} in my webview but in fist time load webview it will return "text/html..." and then webview will working with exactly height. I don't know fix it. Can you give me your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem was I had `javaScriptEnabled={false}`.

After enabling it everything worked.

Answer (score 34):

I wrap WebView inside a View, and set the height from the View.

```
<View style={{ height: 200 }}>
  <WebView
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    source={{uri: 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/24156534?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0'}}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: Your wrap trick worked in my project. You are saved my hours, thanks.

Comment: how to set height as 'auto' . Setting auto height is not working

Comment: hi.. i am also working on vimeo video in webview.  but for me in android "fullscreen" button is not coming up in android. why is that? pls help

Comment: @Kartiikeya did you got any solution? I also want to do something like height: auto

Answer (score 16):

I just follow this guide: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native and succeeded in my work. Here is solution:
1. Define script to send document height to native env after loaded website.
2. Handle onMesssage of webview component and reset Height via state.

```
const webViewScript = `
  setTimeout(function() { 
    window.postMessage(document.documentElement.scrollHeight); 
  }, 500);
  true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
`;


...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      webheight:100,
    }

...

<WebView style={{height: this.state.webheight}}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  source={{uri: "http://<your url>"}}
  onMessage={event => {
    this.setState({webheight: parseInt(event.nativeEvent.data)});
  }}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  injectedJavaScript ={webViewScript}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
></WebView>
```

Hope that help!

Comment: Thanks. This worked with expo react native. I only had to make the minor change to use `useWebKit={true}` otherwise it did not work for me.

Comment: it uses `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage` instead of `window.postMessage`

Comment: Quick tip: set default value to 1000 instead of 100 and let it shrink. This creates better UX

Comment: For my case, I used `Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.clientHeight, document.body.scrollHeight)` to get the real height.

Answer (score 10):

A reliable implementation of this behavior is with `useAutoheight` hook from [@formidable-webview/webshell](https://formidable-webview.github.io/webshell/) library.
The latter allows to inject "features" into `WebViews`, e.g. scripts and behaviors.
In this example, we will use 3 features + the aforementioned hook:

- `HandleHTMLDimensionsFeature` which is required by `useAutoheight` hook to get document size updates;
- `ForceResponsiveViewportFeature` to work around [mobile virtual viewport](https://formidable-webview.github.io/webshell/docs/autoheight/#mobile-virtual-viewport);
- `ForceElementSizeFeature` to work around [cyclic size constraints](https://formidable-webview.github.io/webshell/docs/autoheight/#cyclic-size-constraints-%E2%88%9E)

This component should work with any webpage.

```js
import React from 'react';
import makeWebshell, {
  HandleHTMLDimensionsFeature,
  ForceResponsiveViewportFeature,
  ForceElementSizeFeature,
  useAutoheight
} from '@formidable-webview/webshell';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

const Webshell = makeWebshell(
  WebView,
  new HandleHTMLDimensionsFeature(),
  new ForceResponsiveViewportFeature({ maxScale: 1 }),
  new ForceElementSizeFeature({
    target: 'body',
    heightValue: 'auto',
    widthValue: 'auto'
  })
);

export default function ResilientAutoheightWebView(props) {
  const { autoheightWebshellProps } = useAutoheight({
    webshellProps: props
  });
  return <Webshell {...autoheightWebshellProps} />;
}
```

More resources:

- [Try this on Expo](https://expo.io/@jsamr/projects/formidable-webview-autoheight-example)
- [Full guide here.](https://formidable-webview.github.io/webshell/docs/autoheight/)

Answer (score 10):

Using `postMessage` and `onMessage` like below worked for me perfectly.
Credit to [iamdhj](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/413#issuecomment-473507895)

```
 onWebViewMessage = (event: WebViewMessageEvent) => {
    this.setState({webViewHeight: Number(event.nativeEvent.data)})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <WebView
          style={{ height: this.state.webViewHeight }}
          source={{html: '...'}}
          onMessage={this.onWebViewMessage}
          injectedJavaScript='window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight)'
        />
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! on react-native with Expo

Comment: For my case, I used `Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.clientHeight, document.body.scrollHeight)` to get the real height.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the content height by injecting the JS code as suggested by @ken-ratanachai-s. Although, You will experience certain irregularities in some devices (Extra height after the content). This is becuase the javascript returns the content height in pixels, but we need to use display points in react native. To fix this, Divide the height from javascript with the pixel ratio as follows.

```jsx
import { WebView, PixelRatio } from 'react-native'

const [webviewHeight, setWebviewHeight] = useState(0)

const onProductDetailsWebViewMessage = event => {
    setWebviewHeight(Number(event.nativeEvent.data)/PixelRatio.get())
}

return <WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    style={{ height: productDetailsWebviewHeight }}
    onMessage={onProductDetailsWebViewMessage}
    injectedJavaScript='window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight)'
    source={{ html: "..." }}
/>
```

Pixel ratio ref.: https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio

Courtesy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65976827/5321660

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/413#issuecomment-473507895

Answer (score 3):

The WebView has default styles. If you want to set height, you also need to add `flex: 0`, as stated [in the documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#style):

*Please note that there are default styles (example: you need to add flex: 0 to the style if you want to use height property).*

Answer (score 3):

I made a little component to make this functionality reusable if it helps anyone!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import WebView from "react-native-webview";

const DynamicHeightWebView = (props) => {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const webViewScript = `
    setTimeout(function() { 
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(document.documentElement.scrollHeight); 
    }, 500);
    true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
  `;
  return <WebView
    {...props}
    style={{
      ...props.style,
      height: height,
    }}
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    onMessage={event => {
      setHeight(parseInt(event.nativeEvent.data));
    }}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    injectedJavaScript ={webViewScript}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    useWebKit={true}
  />
}

export default DynamicHeightWebView;
```

Comment: Hm, why setTimeout work, if without setTimeout, i have a little height of html?

Answer (score 2):

I waste whole day to fix the height issue but in the end I had to shift to another library
This one is easy and good

> https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html

Comment: lacking of onFinished method, so we will never know exact height of the view after finish rendering.

Answer (score 1):

use package react-native-autoheight-webview

Answer (score 1):

I recommend react-native-autoheight-webview.
it perfect work for me.
https://github.com/iou90/react-native-autoheight-webview

**UPDATE:**
Best answer is @Ken Ratanachai S.'s answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65976827/9757656

Comment: It doesn't work perfectly. Returns incorrect height for many HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of props injectedJavaScript you can use onLoadEnd and method injectJavaScript. In this case I always got the correct height. The code is something like this:

```
...
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
const webViewRef = useRef(null);
const script = 'window.postMessage(document.documentElement.scrollHeight);';
...
return (
    <WebView
        ref={webViewRef}
        source={{ html: '...' }}
        style={{ height }}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        onLoadEnd={() => webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(script)}
        onMessage={(event) => setHeight(event.nativeEvent.data)}
    />
);
...
```