# How to set height of React Native Webview?

Tags: webview, react-native

I don't know how to find out the height of the webview which comes from an external source. I tried using the height of the display and on iOS it looks fine, but on Android the webview is cut and only the part visible on the display is shown (not possible to scroll down).

Comment: Use the Dimensions component from react-native

Comment: The Dimensions component gives me the height of the display and I used it. With that approach if the webview has height > displayHeight, then it is cut to the height of the display.

Comment: can you share your webview code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native: webview height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446209/react-native-webview-height)

Comment: @JulesSam.Randolph seems like it does. Can't test it because I don't have RN installed anymore, but based on the Question & Answers, seems like that question is same as mine.