# How to set webview heigh to auto react native?

Tags: css, react-native

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    viewQuestion: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    question: {
        flex: 1,
        margin: 5
    }
});

    <View style={styles.viewQuestion} resizeMode={'contain'}>
         <Text style={{fontSize: 17, margin: 10, color: '#000'}}>{this.state.pointer}</Text>
         <WebView source={{html: this.state.item}} style={styles.question}/>
    </View>
```

I was set the view and webview with with `flex: 1`, but it does not work. How to make webview height to `auto`? I also set the `height: 'auto'` in webview style, but that does not work as swell,  help and thanks

Comment: Did you just try { width: "100%", height: "100%" } ?

Comment: yes, but the height of the **Webview** follows the height of the **text**. What I'm looking for is high to be auto for webview, because the content of the webview is a dynamic statement.

Comment: Weird. Yah i have mine working fullscreen but I don't have text component inside:
`<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <WebView
          source={{ uri: 'https://mywebsite.local' }}
          style={{ marginTop: 0 }}
          onLoadProgress={e => this.setState({ loading: e.nativeEvent.progress < 1 })}
        />
</SafeAreaView>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native: webview height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446209/react-native-webview-height)