# How to make React Native Webview auto height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

I need to render some HTML code in my React Native app. But it seems like the WebView can't be set to auto height. Please help me with this problem. This is my code.

```
<View style={{
                    paddingLeft: 18,
                    paddingRight: 18,
                    paddingTop: 10,
                    paddingBottom: 10,
                }}>
                    <WebView source={{
                        html: HTML
                    }}
                        javaScriptEnabled={true}
                        style={{
                            height: 200,
                            backgroundColor: colors.white,
                            marginTop: 20
                        }} />
                </View>
```

As you can see here, I need to define a specific value to the height prop. How can I make its height dynamic, based on the inner HTML content height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest you use the `react-native-autoheight-webview` which gives you the auto height webview for React Native.

You can check it here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autoheight-webview

Comment: Note: if there is any height problem , change scalesPageToFit={true} to scalesPageToFit={false}

Answer (score -2):

I wrap WebView inside a View, and set the height from the View.

```
<View style={{ height: 200 }}>
  <WebView
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    source={{uri: 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/24156534?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0'}}
  />
</View>
```

heres where i get the answer pls give him credit... [React native: webview height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446209/react-native-webview-height)

Comment: minHeight is working as same as height prop

Comment: yes but it has other purposes... why not try it :)

Comment: You copied it from here directly - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446209/react-native-webview-height

Comment: if it works feel free to upvote and check it as answer to help other people if they had the same problem

Comment: i dont really want the points i just really love helping people

Comment: it is not even the answer to the question. we don't need to wrap webview to set the height anyway. The problem here is how to set the height as dynamic as per the content inside it.