# ReactNative 0.28: Resizing WebView based on content height

Tags: webview, react-native

I'm basically asking the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952270/react-native-is-it-possible-to-have-the-height-of-a-html-content-in-a-webview), but for RN 0.28+.  The solutions presented in the various answers do not seem to work in RN 0.28, so I'm hoping there are other configurations or hacks...

Is there any way to resize a WebView based on the height of its content? I've tried injecting the document height into the title and reading that back with `onNavigationStateChange`, but it always returns `568` (similar to [the comments to this gist](https://gist.github.com/dbasedow/ed6e099823cb8d5ab30e)).

```
 return <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log('touched ' + this.props.choice.id)}
                           style={styles.choiceRowWrapper} >
      <View style={styles.choiceWebViewWrapper}>
        <WebView automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                 javascriptEnabled={true}
                 onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => this._updateWebViewNavState(navState)}
                 scrollEnabled={false}
                 source={{html: WrapHTML(this.props.choice.text)}}
                 style={[styles.choiceWebView, {height: this.state.height}]} />
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
 }
  _updateWebViewNavState = (navState) => {
    console.log(navState);
    if (navState.title) {
      this.setState({ height: parseInt(navState.title) });
    }
  }

function WrapHTML (markup) {
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body class="content">
          ${markup}
        </body>
        <script>window.location.hash = 1;document.title = document.height;</script>
      </html>`;
  };
```

I have also tried various things inside of the WebView document, like:

```
document.scrollHeight.contentSize.height
document.body.height
```

But all of them are undefined. The closest I got was something like this (from [this iOS SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745160/how-to-determine-uiwebview-height-based-on-content-within-a-variable-height-uit)):

```
document.getElementById("content").offsetHeight;
```

But for short text content that returns 20, and for a longer text content (one full sentence) it returns 40...neither of which seems accurate.

I also started trying [this RN component](https://github.com/almost/react-native-html-webview), but the repo indicates that it is not being actively maintained -- the latest version on `npm` doesn't support RN 0.28 because of the change they made for importing React by itself (instead of from ReactNative).

Has anyone gotten WebViews to resize properly with RN 0.28?

Comment: Any luck with this issue?

Comment: Sorry, not really. We wound up hacking it and then moving away from RN to focus on a web-based implementation, so didn't find a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and tinkering, I found this approach which is a slightly more involved version of setting the document title to the screen height value.  In my tests, this has worked on both Android and iOS with react native 0.47.

https://gist.github.com/xyos/dcaa43fa561760b9d6194d78e5fb7721