# onLayout not triggering on WebView

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use `onLayout` on my `WebView` but it's not triggering.

```
export default class Sandbox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.fill}>
        <WebView
          onLayout={(event) => {
            console.log(event.nativeEvent.layout)
          }}
          source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fill: {
    flex: 1,
  },
})
```

Have someone an idea about why this isn't triggering? I checked the documentation and it seems to be available to be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the WebView dimensions you can use the `onLayout` on the container view.
Otherwise, If you need to get the dimensions of the HTML content you can have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952270/react-native-is-it-possible-to-have-the-height-of-a-html-content-in-a-webview) or use `onContentSizeChange` on Android.