# PhantomJS rendered screenshot is much higher than the actual page

Tags: javascript, css, height, phantomjs

I'm creating a website screenshot using PhantomJS 1.9.8 experiencing the problem, that the created PNG is much higher than the actual website as seen in the screenshot. There is a not yet ended discussion about PhantomJS not respecting viewport size here:  https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10619

But i think in my case it's more or less a problem with font size and/or type as you can notice also in the image.

Maybe somebody was facing the same problem and could provide a possible 'workaround' for that, as i need the screenshot to have the identical size as the website itself.

[image]

The following **HTML** is used for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WSST</title>
        <script src="js/test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style = "background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <span class = "hey">Page Start</span>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    Page End
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the JS file passed to PhantomJS:

```
var args = require('system').args;
var page = require('webpage').create();

var width = args[3];
var height = args[4];

page.viewportSize = {
    width: width,
    height: height
};


page.open(args[1], function(status) {

    console.log('phantomjs: width ' + width + ' height ' + height);
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    if(status === "success") {
        page.render(args[2] + '.png');
    }
    phantom.exit();

});
```

Explanation of the **Arguments**:

1. URL of the website
2. filename of the rendered image
3. width of the user's viewport
4. height of the user's viewport

3 and 4 are actually calculated by the javascript file 'test.js' that is loaded with the HTML in the following way as suggested here [How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript)

```
var body = document.body,
                html = document.documentElement;

            var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
                html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
            var width = Math.max( body.scrollWidth, body.offsetWidth,
                html.clientWidth, html.clientWidth, html.offsetWidth );
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding a reset.css stylesheet?

Comment: I just tried with this https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/source/browse/website/reset.css?r=cbdd80e98ea1eb29d5d3a9c65c84798b472b59b1 That changed the layout of the page in my local browser but the phantomjs picture stays exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with CSS stylesheets, i found out that this issue is solved by using fixed font-sizes for **all** elements on my page.

Obviously this issue is caused by PhantomJS / WebKit relying on 'it's own' font-sizes when they are not defined explicitly.