# Webview autoheight to content is not working on iOS (Appcelerator Titanium)

Tags: webview, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I want to add webview which height would be as it content. I make it running smoothly on Android but on iOS the longer the text is the longer space below text is.

Here is my code:

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    layout: 'vertical',
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});

    var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({
        height: 200,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    });

    var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE,     
        html: '<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2"></head><body style="margin:0; background-color: blue">Some page some text2</body></html>'
    });

    var view2 = Ti.UI.createView({
        height: 200,
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    });

    scrollView.add(view1);
    scrollView.add(webview);
    scrollView.add(view2);

    window.add(scrollView);

window.open();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's a bug / discouraged method for iOS. No direct workaround. Can be checked here:
[Jira Ticket about problem with iOS 9](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23123),
[Jira Ticket about problem with webView + ScrollView](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20587)

Answer (score 2):

The webview doesn't know the size of the content. But you can ASK the webview how high the content is.

For this you need to use [evalJS](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView-method-evalJS).

Use the JS found on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript):

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
```

and preferably put this in a function inside the webview. Lets say the above Javascript is in function `getDocumentHeight` and that function returns the `height` property. Now, to get the height use eval like this:

```
var height = webview.evalJS('getDocumentHeight()');
webview.height = height;
```

Now, you want this to execute every time the content is loaded, assuming the content changes, so in that case you can watch the `load` event ([doc here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView-event-load)) and trigger the `evalJS` above every time this event is fired.

It will not be very pretty, as the webview is not intended to scale like this, but it works.

Comment: Agree this is not pretty, but the only way I have found to make it work. And I've tried for years!

Comment: This method gives same height as Ti.UI.SIZE. For example text: 'Some page some text2 Some page some text2 Some page some text2' will return height: 240 (where on Android it is 38 and  that's proper value) so there is still gap below. Please try the code.

Comment: The strange thing is that height is not increasing as line function. For example: if on iOS is 240 than the real height is 38 (~6.31x), if it is 7060 than the real height is 931 (~7.58x). The value is same for all iOS devices (iPhone 5/6, iPad Pro) and it is also surprising (gap on Iphone 5 is smaller than on iPad Pro).

Comment: It seems that on iOS the height returned is somehow connected with number of characters.
If on Android we have 4 lines of text (height: 76), than on iOS (depending on character quantity) we will have values  like: 560, 640, 720, 800. But for 5 lines of text (height: 96 on Android) we will start with ~880 on iOS.