# JQuery CSS height body

Tags: jquery, css

I want to have the body `height` in CSS based on the document `height`.

This code doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("body").css({"height": $(document).height() * 4 }, 300);

});
```

Comment: why don't you try `html, body { height: 100%; }` or `body { height: 100vh; }`? I see you are multiplying by 4, you can do that in CSS with `400%` or `400vh` as well

Comment: It is not what I want. I just need this code work with $(document).height() or an other function

Comment: Use pure css as suggested Aziz. Dont make things complicated

Comment: It is for this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833141/calculate-the-height-of-document?noredirect=1#comment65329837_38833141

Comment: So yes I need JS, and not only css

Comment: `$("body").css({"height": $(document).height()* 4 + "px" });`

Comment: @user3870112, is this that you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/vs36ur9L/70/

Comment: try `$(window).height()` instead of `$(document).height()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var winHeight = $(window).height() * 4;

    $("body").css({"height": winHeight + "px" });

});
```