# Get Document Height in Angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular

I need to convert some jQuery code to Angular 2 and am having some trouble figuring out how to get the height of the document.

The jQuery code I have used is

```
$(document).height();
```

How would I achieve this in Angular 2?

Thanks

Comment: $document.height(); in angular

Comment: Try element[0].offsetHeight

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. After further research I believe I have found the solution to be `document.body.scrollHeight`. This code a height value regardless of the height of the window.

Answer (score 4):

Using `document.height` doesn't work in angular 2 aswell as in the console.

```js
console.log(window.outerHeight);
console.log(window.innerHeight);
console.log(screen.height);
```

Comment: Unfortunately these all return the window height rather than the document height which should not vary depending on the window height.

Comment: @JonathanHutchinson I've edited my post, check these options and let me know if it works for you. These functions doesn't vary on the window/browser height.The value they return is static.

Comment: Thanks @K. Daniek but unfortunately none of these work. Both `screen.height` and 'window.innerHeight` return the window height and 'window.outerHeight` returns the height of the browser window (it changes if you reduce the height from full screen). There is a div.container-fluid element which I think matches the height of the document. Do you know how I could reference this in Angular2?

Comment: @JonathanHutchinson But what exactly do you want to achieve? I've given you like all ways to get the height of all screens or windows. What else?

Comment: I needed a way of returning the document height which should remain static regardless of the height of the window. I achieved this with `document.body.scrollHeight`. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @JonathanHutchinson That's cool. I'm in need of rep points. If you would upvote, would be great.

Answer (score 1):

What about just using `document.height` without jQuery?

<strike>document.height</strike>

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/height

This worked in the Plunker

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/IXeZR502yYHh2sucfIrP?p=preview)

Comment: It doesn't work. Tried to do it in angular 2 and simply in the console. Neither of them worked

Comment: `document.documentElement.clientHeight` returns a value, however this varies depending on the height of the window suggesting this is the window height rather than the height of the actual document. What I need is the height of the document which should not change on account of the window height.

Comment: Then it's probanly `document.body.clientHeight` what you want

Comment: Thanks @Günter Zöchbauer but again it seems to return the window size and not the full document