# How to trigger a JavaScript function when the scroll bar reaches a certain percentage of the page height

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I am looking for a solution written in plain JavaScript that fires a JS function at a certain percentage of a page scroll (say 80%). I am looking to accomplish something similar to what [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) does, without 750 lines of code or using jQuery.

I'm assuming I would figure determine the height of the window then trigger the callback once the scroll point is greater than 80% of the height.

The other requirements here are that I only want it to trigger once. The other concern I have is potential performance issues of constantly polling for the scroll percentage. Is this a valid concern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way that will check the page scroll once every 500ms while scrolling, and will only run once:

```js
var throttledListener = throttle(scrollListener, 500);
window.addEventListener('scroll', throttledListener);

function throttle(func, delay) { // allows [func] to run once every [delay] ms
    var func = func.bind(func),
        last = Date.now();
    return function() {
        if (Date.now() - last > delay) {
            func();
            last = Date.now();
        }
    }
}
function scrollListener() {
    console.log('scrolled');
    var threshold = document.body.clientHeight * 0.6;
    if (window.pageYOffset >= threshold) {
        alert('user scrolled to threshold; listener removed');
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', throttledListener);
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="height:2000px;width:100%">tall div</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use onscroll

> function trigerScroll(ev){
>       if(window.pageYOffset>400)alert('User has scrolled at least 400 px!'); } window.onscroll=trigerScroll ;

Edit:

you can get the document height like this

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
```

source : [How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript)

Comment: Your snippet isn't working for me. [Here](http://codepen.io/protechig/pen/VPbbPR?editors=1111) is a working codepen of what i'm working with. I tried to have it just `console.log()` something on scroll and it doesn't look like it's triggering.

Comment: `window.onscroll=trigerScroll()` should be `window.onscroll=trigerScroll`