# Get Height of document in React

Tags: reactjs, dom, ecmascript-6, components, jsx

How do you find the height of the entire document on page load in React? So in jQuery it would look something like:

```
$(document).height();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: document.documentElement.offsetHeight

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript

Comment: React is not a DOM utility library, it doesn't provide any functionality for that. You get the height in exactly the same way as you do without React.

Answer (score 10):

I just spent some serious time figuring some things out with React and scrolling events / positions - so for those still looking, here's what I found:

The viewport height can be found by using `window.innerHeight` or by using `document.documentElement.clientHeight`. (Current viewport height)

The height of the entire document (body) can be found using `window.document.body.offsetHeight`.

If you're attempting to find the height of the document and know when you've hit the bottom - here's what I came up with:

```
if (window.pageYOffset >= this.myRefII.current.clientHeight &&
  Math.round((document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight))
  < document.documentElement.scrollHeight - 72) {
    this.setState({ trueOrNot: true });
  } else {
    this.setState({ trueOrNot: false });
  }
}
```

(My navbar was 72px in fixed position, thus the -72 to get a better scroll-event trigger)

Lastly, here are a number of scroll commands to console.log(), which helped me figure out my math actively.

```
console.log('window inner height: ', window.innerHeight);

console.log('document Element client hieght: ', document.documentElement.clientHeight);

console.log('document Element scroll hieght: ', document.documentElement.scrollHeight);

console.log('document Element offset height: ', document.documentElement.offsetHeight);

console.log('document element scrolltop: ', document.documentElement.scrollTop);

console.log('window page Y Offset: ', window.pageYOffset);

console.log('window document body offsetheight: ', window.document.body.offsetHeight);
```

Whew! Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Thank you for answering this question! I just made some formatting changes, hopefully they are an improvement. If so, you can click the `edit` button to see the source code I used to achieve this formatting, so you can use it in your future posts. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'll be sure to include the backticks in the future.  Definitely reads better.

Answer (score 4):

Its worker for me:

```
document.documentElement.offsetHeight
```

Comment: This solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finding the height of document on page load is a too tricky, in my opinion!
However, finding it after page has loaded is kind of an easier task.
Therefore, try to find it in the "componentDidMount()" function! You can either use:

- `document.documentElement.offsetHeight`
- `$(document).height()`

(The truth is React also has a built-in version of jQuery, so you can actually use the second way to get the height)

For example:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class YourClass extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        // ...
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("document-height",document.documentElement.offsetHeight);
        console.log("jQuery-document-height",$(document).height());
    }

    render(){
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: I get $ is not defined when using $(document).height() in React.