# How to animate element along svg path on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, scroll

**I have an issue:** I have to change element position&angle on scroll event. Like my `webpage` is a long road with background - and I need to animate car movements along this path during the scroll.

**I good explanation is here:** `http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr-path/` - a perfect solution, that meets my requirements. But Unfortunately it's extremely outdated.

Maybe somebody has an up to date solution-library? Or code-ideas, how to animate element via `svg-path` with page `scrolling`?

Also i tried http://scrollmagic.io/examples/expert/bezier_path_animation.html - but it's not something that I need, because my path is difficult. Not just a couple of circles.

Comment: What does "outdated" mean?  If it works, what does it matter if it is four years old?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau it doesn't work with android 4.4, MacOS etc. It makes a huge problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is some vanilla Javascript that moves a "car" along a path according to how much the page has scrolled.

It should work in all (most) browsers.  The part that you may need to tweak is how we get the page height (`document.documentElement.scrollHeight`). You may need to [use different methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript) depending on the browsers you want to support.

```js
function positionCar()
{
  var  scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
  var  maxScrollY = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  var  path = document.getElementById("path1");
  // Calculate distance along the path the car should be for the current scroll amount
  var  pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
  var  dist = pathLen * scrollY / maxScrollY;
  var  pos = path.getPointAtLength(dist);
  // Calculate position a little ahead of the car (or behind if we are at the end), so we can calculate car angle
  if (dist + 1 <= pathLen) {
    var  posAhead = path.getPointAtLength(dist + 1);
    var  angle = Math.atan2(posAhead.y - pos.y, posAhead.x - pos.x);
  } else {
    var  posBehind = path.getPointAtLength(dist - 1);
    var  angle = Math.atan2(pos.y - posBehind.y, pos.x - posBehind.x);
  }
  // Position the car at "pos" totated by "angle"
  var  car = document.getElementById("car");
  car.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + pos.x + "," + pos.y + ") rotate(" + rad2deg(angle) + ")");
}

function rad2deg(rad) {
  return 180 * rad / Math.PI;
}

// Reposition car whenever there is a scroll event
window.addEventListener("scroll", positionCar);

// Position the car initially
positionCar();
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 3000px;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500"
     viewBox="0 0 672.474 933.78125">
  <g transform="translate(-54.340447,-64.21875)" id="layer1">
   <path d="m 60.609153,64.432994 c 0,0 -34.345187,72.730986 64.649767,101.015256 98.99494,28.28427 321.2285,-62.62946 321.2285,-62.62946 0,0 131.31984,-52.527932 181.82746,16.16244 50.50763,68.69037 82.04198,196.41856 44.44671,284.86302 -30.25843,71.18422 -74.75128,129.29952 -189.90867,133.34013 -115.15739,4.04061 -72.73099,-153.54318 -72.73099,-153.54318 0,0 42.42641,-129.29953 135.36044,-119.198 92.93404,10.10152 -14.14213,-129.29953 -141.42135,-94.95434 -127.27922,34.34518 -183.84777,80.8122 -206.07112,121.2183 -22.22336,40.40611 -42.06243,226.23742 -26.26397,305.06607 8.77013,43.75982 58.20627,196.1403 171.72594,270.72088 73.8225,48.50019 181.82745,2.02031 181.82745,2.02031 0,0 94.95434,-12.12183 78.7919,-155.56349 -16.16244,-143.44166 -111.68403,-138.77778 -139.9683,-138.77778 -28.28427,0 83.39976,-156.18677 83.39976,-156.18677 0,0 127.27922,-189.90867 107.07617,16.16245 C 634.3758,640.21994 864.69058,888.71747 591.94939,941.2454 319.2082,993.77334 -16.162441,539.20469 153.54319,997.81395"
    id="path1"
    style="fill:none;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:4;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"/>


    <path id="car" d="M-15,-10 L15,0 L -15,10 z" fill="yellow" stroke="red" stroke-width="7.06"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you) but with this svg it won't work :( https://jsfiddle.net/oj1aeq3y/1/ & https://jsfiddle.net/oj1aeq3y/2/

Comment: for example if I have such an svg:
https://pastebin.com/raw/gT6PXjq7 and my page is very long (something like ~4530px) and this animation has to run over the whole page

Comment: Your track is not a single line down the page. It is a filled shape that runs up the page and then back down to the bottom.  Fix your path so that it is a single line starting at the top, and ending at the bottom. It should work then.

Comment: oh, what a pitty :( maybe you know a good software to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I adapted Paul LeBau's answer for my purposes in TypeScript and figured I'd leave it here in case it's helpful for anyone.

NOTE: It's broken as hell when running the snippet in Stack Overflow. No clue why when it functions perfectly in VSCode. First thing I'd recommended is full screening the snippet if you can't see the SVG. Then actually try copy/pasting this into your own project before making any claims about there being an issue with the posted code.

Notable additions from Paul's:

1. A clickToScroll function allowing you to click anywhere on the svg path and have it scroll accordingly (does not work at all in the SO snippet window)
2. The car (rider) will face towards the direction it's moving

Here's the Typescript version separately as SO doesn't support TS :(

```
interface PathRider {
    ride: () => void;
    clickToScroll: (e: MouseEvent) => void;
    onClick: (e: MouseEvent, callback: (pt: DOMPoint) => void) => void;
};
    
const usePathRider = (
    rider: SVGPathElement,
    path: SVGPathElement,
    rideOnInit = true
): PathRider => {
    const maxScrollY = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    const pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
    
    //====================
    /* Helper Functions */
    
    const radToDeg = (rad: number) => (180 * rad) / Math.PI;
    
    const distance = (a: DOMPoint, b: DOMPoint) =>
        Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2) + Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2));
    
    //=========================
    /* Click-based Functions */
    
    const step = 0.5; // how granularly it should check for the point on the path closest to where the user clicks. the lower the value the less performant the operation is
    let currLen = -step;
    const pointArr: DOMPoint[] = [];
    while ((currLen += step) <= pathLen)
        pointArr.push(path.getPointAtLength(currLen));

    const onClick = (e: MouseEvent, callback: (pt: DOMPoint) => void) => {
        let pt = new DOMPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        callback(pt.matrixTransform(path.getScreenCTM().inverse()));
    };
    
    const getLengthAtPoint = (pt: DOMPoint) => {
        let bestGuessIdx = 0;
        let bestGuessDist = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        let guessDist: number;
    
        pointArr.forEach((point, idx) => {
            if ((guessDist = distance(pt, point)) < bestGuessDist) {
                bestGuessDist = guessDist;
                bestGuessIdx = idx;
            }
        });
    
        return bestGuessIdx * step;
    };
    
    const getScrollPosFromLength = (len: number) => (len * maxScrollY) / pathLen;
    
    const clickToScroll = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        onClick(e, (point) => {
            const lengthAtPoint = getLengthAtPoint(point);
            const scrollPos = getScrollPosFromLength(lengthAtPoint);
    
            window.scrollTo({
                top: scrollPos,
                behavior: 'smooth',
            });
        });
    };

    //==========================
    /* Scroll-based functions */
    
    let lastDist: number; // for determining direction
    const ride = () => {
        const scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
        const dist = (pathLen * scrollY) / maxScrollY;
        const pos = path.getPointAtLength(dist);
        let angle: number;
    
        // calculate position a little ahead of the rider (or behind if we are at the end),
        //  so we can calculate the rider angle
        const dir = lastDist < dist; // true=right
        if (dir ? dist + 1 <= pathLen : dist - 1 >= 0) {
            const nextPos = path.getPointAtLength(dist + (dir ? 1 : -1));
            angle = Math.atan2(nextPos.y - pos.y, nextPos.x - pos.x);
        } else {
            const nextPos = path.getPointAtLength(dist + (dir ? -1 : 1));
            angle = Math.atan2(pos.y - nextPos.y, pos.x - nextPos.x);
        }
    
        lastDist = dist;
    
        rider.setAttribute(
            'transform',
            `translate(${pos.x}, ${pos.y}) rotate(${radToDeg(angle)})`
        );
    };
    
    if (rideOnInit) ride();
    
    return {
        ride,
        clickToScroll,
        onClick,
    };
};
```

Snippets for running in SO

```js
const usePathRider = (
  rider,
  path,
  rideOnInit = true
) => {
  const maxScrollY = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  const pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
  const step = 0.5;

  let currLen = -step;
  const pointArr = [];
  while ((currLen += step) <= pathLen)
    pointArr.push(path.getPointAtLength(currLen));

  //====================
  /* Helper Functions */

  const radToDeg = (rad) => (180 * rad) / Math.PI;

  const distance = (a, b) =>
    Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2) + Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2));

  //============
  /* Closures */

  const onClick = (e, callback) => {
    let pt = new DOMPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    callback(pt.matrixTransform(path.getScreenCTM().inverse()));
  };

  const getLengthAtPoint = (pt) => {
    let bestGuessIdx = 0;
    let bestGuessDist = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    let guessDist;

    pointArr.forEach((point, idx) => {
      if ((guessDist = distance(pt, point)) < bestGuessDist) {
        bestGuessDist = guessDist;
        bestGuessIdx = idx;
      }
    });

    return bestGuessIdx * step;
  };

  const getScrollPosFromLength = (len) => (len * maxScrollY) / pathLen;

  const clickToScroll = (e) => {
    onClick(e, (point) => {
      const lengthAtPoint = getLengthAtPoint(point);
      const scrollPos = getScrollPosFromLength(lengthAtPoint);

      window.scrollTo({
        top: scrollPos,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    });
  };

  let lastDist;
  const ride = () => {
    const scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
    const dist = (pathLen * scrollY) / maxScrollY;
    const pos = path.getPointAtLength(dist);
    let angle;

    // calculate position a little ahead of the rider (or behind if we are at the end),
    //  so we can calculate the rider angle
    const dir = lastDist < dist; // true=right
    if (dir ? dist + 1 <= pathLen : dist - 1 >= 0) {
      const nextPos = path.getPointAtLength(dist + (dir ? 1 : -1));
      angle = Math.atan2(nextPos.y - pos.y, nextPos.x - pos.x);
    } else {
      const nextPos = path.getPointAtLength(dist + (dir ? -1 : 1));
      angle = Math.atan2(pos.y - nextPos.y, pos.x - nextPos.x);
    }

    lastDist = dist;

    rider.setAttribute(
      'transform',
      `translate(${pos.x}, ${pos.y}) rotate(${radToDeg(angle)})`
    );
  };

  if (rideOnInit) ride();

  return {
    ride,
    clickToScroll,
    onClick,
  };
};


/* VANILLA JS USAGE */

const svgRider = document.getElementById('rider');
const svgPath = document.getElementById('path');

const pathRider = usePathRider(svgRider, svgPath);

// Reposition car whenever there is a scroll event
window.addEventListener("scroll", pathRider.ride);
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 3000px;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<svg onclick="pathRider.clickToScroll" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 300 285" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision"><path
            id="path"
            d="M22.061031,163.581791c.750375-2.251126,2.251125-16.508254,26.263131-20.26013s20.26013-8.254128,42.02101,2.251125q21.76088,10.505253-12.006004,18.009005-33.016508.750374,0-18.009005t52.526263,4.427213q6.003001,19.584792,19.134567,14.332166t16.133067-14.332166q32.266133-12.081041,45.772886,0t47.273637,0"
            transform="translate(.000002 0.000001)"
            fill="none"
            stroke="#3f5787"
            stroke-width="0.6"
            stroke-dasharray="3"
        />
        <path
            id="rider"
            d="M-2,-2 L3,0 L -2,2 z"
            stroke="red"
            stroke-width="0.6"
        /></svg
    >
```