# WebView in ListView without assigning its dimensions

Tags: listview, webview, flutter

Is there any possibility to put `WebView` (webview_flutter) inside a `ListView` without assigning its dimensions but automatically adopt its height. Only working solution I found is to put WebView in Container by assigning its height but I dont want to assign any height I just want it to occupy height according to its content..

I have tried so many solutions including `Expanded` for this but getting error about infinite height . Any solution?

Comment: Can you explain it little bit more ? maybe with pictures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sorry it's late but now it's working properly.

I wrapped WebView into a SizedBox and assigned it's height like this:

```
              _webViewController
                  .evaluateJavascript("document.body.clientHeight")
                  .then((height) {
                print("Height of Page is: $height}");
                setState(() {
                      sizedBoxHeight = double.parse(height);
                    });
              });
```

For a more advanced solution we can use JavascriptChannels like this:

```
            javascriptChannels: Set.from([
              JavascriptChannel(
                  name: 'RenderedWebViewHeight',
                  onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
                      setState(() {
                        sizedBoxHeight = double.parse(message.message);
                      });

            ]),
```

In JavaScript, we can do something like this.

```
onload="RenderedWebViewHeight.postMessage(document.body.clientHeight);"
```

Now we can see it's dynamically calculating the height of WebView which is wrapped in a SizedBox with the height WebView so we can put it into a ListView.

For a more detailed solution, you can look at [webview_flutter_plus](https://github.com/shah-xad/webview_flutter_plus).

Edit:

```
 document.documentElement.scrollHeight
```

is the most accurate way of doing things. This works with both body margins and margins of stuff inside the body pushing it downwards.
More info in [How to get height of entire document with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44077777/5980046)

Comment: The link seems broken

Comment: I have adjusted that broken link.

Comment: Link broken again!  This looks like just what I need, and a bit beyond my present capability to fathom.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes the app crash: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104889

Answer (score 3):

Until now you can not as I expect...but you can include a scroll inside your webview widget

import those libraries:

import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

add this line to your webview widget:

```
gestureRecognizers: Set()..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(()=>VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
```

and you are done :)

**EDIT**
the flutter_widget_from_html plugin is now supporting the webview and iframe and you can use it insted of the web_view plugin and without the need of using a height