# how to calculate the height of a variable height page?

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have a page which content always changes, how can I calculate the height of the whole page included what is scrolled hidden. I tried `window.innerHeight` but it only shows me the height of the visible area of the page. How can I how tall is my page from the very top to the very end, assuming I have to scroll in order to see it completely?

Comment: `document.body.scrollHeight` should be your friend.

Comment: In particular, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44077777/1264804