# Make a div css height stretch to the bottom of the body

Tags: css, html, stretch

I'm currently working on a webpage where i have a template and add the content in after so i have a div which changes height depending on the content put in it. i want to put another div down the side which will stretch down to the bottom of the first div no matter what size the original div is.

i have tried doing it by using:

```
    height:100%
```

and a few other methods in CSS

Thanks

Comment: supply relevant css and html please!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Div stretch 100% page height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712689/css-div-stretch-100-page-height)

Comment: @Martin42006 :  you are not supposed to show the PHP and CSS files for download....paste the codes here or give a jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Check here http://jsfiddle.net/nM8Qn/

Comment: @marios this only appears to be working on my code if the wrapper is less that the view port

Comment: @Martin42006 : then please show us your fiddle, so we can help! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor i tried to paste my code into jsfiddle but it doesnt look like it should, i will try and cut out the divs and put them in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a case of a div inside a div and you want the second div to be at the bottom of the first div then.

set for div1:

```
position:absolute;
```

and for div 2:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: @Martin42006 This doesn't set the top of the 2nd div at the bottom of the 1st div. Still it is accepted. Did the top of the 2nd div stretch to the bottom of the 1st. Check this fiddle(**http://jsfiddle.net/x8YE6/**) with this implementation.

Comment: @RajeshPaul no but this sets the bottom of the second div to the bottom of the first div and then i can adjust the heights accordingly