# Setting body height to 100%

Tags: html, css, height

I need to have the body of all my webpages (except homepage) located on http://www.zorglegal.nl to the same height (100% browser height), so the brown bar on the right is stretched full screen from top to bottom. How can I best achieve this?

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

doesn't work. I also tried to set a class for the content element and tried to set it to 100% height but that doesn't work either. How can i do this?

The brown bar is a png image and is set as a background image for a fullwidth container. So if that container is 100% high, it should work. But how?

Comment: 100% height = window size , But when you get scroll that is more the 100%. Currently its working as expected but your requirement is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Div stretch 100% page height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712689/css-div-stretch-100-page-height)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make body have 100% of the browser height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Auto Resize Website Body Based On Resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372832/how-to-auto-resize-website-body-based-on-resolution)

Comment: Please don't refer to your site. That link may be dead or changed tomorrow helping no one in the future. You can insert images here. All markup should also be placed here: [mcve] In addition, you speak of a "brown bar" but I have yet to see it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use viewport height.

```
height: 100vh
```

This means that the div or whatever is as high as the browser window.

Comment: This makes a redundant scrollbar appear on the right a lot of the time.

Answer (score 7):

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;

    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

This Css will help you to set height 100% for every page.

Answer (score 0):

[Body Height to 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372832/how-to-auto-resize-website-body-based-on-resolution/34373028#34373028)

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to achieve using javascript:

```
$(window).bind('resize', yourclassname);
```

In **yourclassname** also use **yourID**, give it to parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `table` property here, for cross-browser support.

```
    html {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    }

    body {
        width:100%;
        display:table-cell;
    }

    html, body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```