# CSS Height (Inside Absolutely Positioned Element)

Tags: css

I'm using the "100% page height" pattern from this SO answer:

[CSS Div stretch 100% page height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712689/css-div-stretch-100-page-height)

In other words I have a basic DOM structure of:

```
<hmtml> // has min-height: 100% and position: absolute
<body>  // has height: 100%
    <div id="myApp"> // has // has position:absolute/top: 0/bottom:0
       <div id="inner"> // has no styles (or height: 100%; same difference)
```

Everything works great with `html`/`body`/`#myApp`: they all have 100% page height.   My problem is the `div#inner`: it doesn't grow to the height of its parent (even if I give it `height: 100%`).

I believe this is happening because `#myApp` is positioned absolutely, and thus has no height for `#inner` to inherit.  Is there any way to fix this without adding `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom:0` to every nested element?  It seems like if I can somehow get `#inner` to take its height from `#main` I can get all of its children to inherit that height ... but because of the absolute positioning I can't figure out how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, body{ height:100%; margin:0; }

#myApp{
  position:absolute;
  top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
  background:red;
}

#inner{
  height:100%;
  background:gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="myApp">
  <div id="inner"> 
    Inner should be gold and it is!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yea, the actual fix that you did was setting html and body to `height: 100%;margin: 0;` , I would mention that

Comment: Great answer, thanks!  One question though: if I have `#myApp #inner #someDiv`, should `#someDiv` inherit the `height: 100%`?  It doesn't seem to be doing so, and if I have to throw `height: 100%` on all the children that's not the end of the world.  But if you know of anyway to make the `height` inherit that would be very handy.

Comment: @machineghost you have the CSS value `inherit`. Also, using `position` (`relative` i.e.) on your inner elements would help.

Comment: @machineghost Also, don't forget that you have the `vh` and `vw` units. I.e: `height:100vh` will set an element to the height of your viewport. (Not sure if fits your requirements but...)

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I hadn't even heard of the `vh`/`vw` units; can't wait to check them out.